# What is the best format for contacts for importing and exporting to iphones, androids and desktop pc's

Tags: android, python, ios, iphone, django

I need to build a small website (Python/Django) for administrate contacts (like: name, phone number, email).
It should be possible to export the data from this website to phones and PCs.
Is there a standard/format/protocol/lib which I should use?

Comment: How is this a Python / Django question actually ?

Comment: Because maybe someone can recommend a python module or django app for doing it. Btw. how is your comment useful?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use simple `csv` files (or `vcard` if you like to include pictures).

Keep in mind that you might run into trouble on iphones (ios is very restrictive in importing contacts from websites)!